# How to use an object detection tensor flow lite model (converted from yolo v5) in android camera app?

Tags: kotlin, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, object-detection-api, yolov5

I'm making an object detection app using kotlin and tensor flow lite model (I used yolo v5 and then converted it to tensor flow lite using the following line:
`python export.py --weights best.pt --include tflite --nms`)
This is the Output Tensor Details:

> Name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
> Shape: [  1 100   4]
> Type: <class 'numpy.float32'>

I added it to the app and used the kotlin sample provided with the model to draw borders over detected objects.
The app is not generating any problems however when I run it on my physical device.
The problem is that it crashes and closes on its own after the splash screen is viewed and displays an error message saying that the app has a bug.
This error is generated in the run:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.example.sightfulkotlin, PID: 23100
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sightfulkotlin/com.example.sightfulkotlin.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: Unexpected failure when preparing tensor allocations: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference.
>     Node number 402 (FlexCombinedNonMaxSuppression) failed to prepare.

I tried the following code to open the camera and draw bounding boxes on the detected objects.

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.sightfulkotlin

import  android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.graphics.*
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.HandlerThread
import android.view.Surface
import android.view.TextureView
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import com.example.sightfulkotlin.ml.ObjectDetection
import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.FileUtil
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var colors = listOf(
        Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.CYAN, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.DKGRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.LTGRAY, Color.WHITE)
    val paint = Paint()
    private lateinit var labels:List<String>
    private lateinit var cameraManager: CameraManager
    lateinit var cameraDevice: CameraDevice
    lateinit var handler: Handler
    lateinit var textureView: TextureView
    lateinit var model: ObjectDetection
    lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
    lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getPermission()

        labels = FileUtil.loadLabels(this, "labels.txt")
        model = ObjectDetection.newInstance(this)


        var imageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder().add(ResizeOp(640, 640, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR)).build()

        val handlerThread = HandlerThread("videoThread")
        handlerThread.start()
        handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)

        paint.color = Color.GREEN
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        textureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView)
        textureView.surfaceTextureListener = object: TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener
        {
            override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(p0: SurfaceTexture, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
                openCamera()
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(p0: SurfaceTexture, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(p0: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(p0: SurfaceTexture) {
                bitmap = textureView.bitmap!!

                var tensorImage = TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32)
                tensorImage.load(bitmap)
                tensorImage = imageProcessor.process(tensorImage)



                val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 640, 640, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
                inputFeature0.loadBuffer(tensorImage.buffer)

                val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
                val locations = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer.floatArray
                val scores = outputs.outputFeature1AsTensorBuffer.floatArray
                val classes = outputs.outputFeature2AsTensorBuffer.floatArray
                val numberOfDetections = outputs.outputFeature3AsTensorBuffer.floatArray


                val mutable = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
                val canvas = Canvas(mutable)

                val h = mutable.height
                val w = mutable.width

                paint.textSize = h/15f
                paint.strokeWidth = h/85f

                scores.forEachIndexed{index, fl ->
                    var x = index
                    x *= 4
                    if(fl > 0.5)
                    {
                        paint.color = colors[index]
                        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
                        canvas.drawRect(RectF(locations[x+1] *w, locations[x] *h, locations[x+3] *w, locations[x+2] *h), paint)
                        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
                        canvas.drawText(labels[classes[index].toInt()] +" "+fl.toString(), locations[x+1] *w, locations[x] *h, paint)
                    }
                }
                imageView.setImageBitmap(mutable)
            }
        }

        cameraManager =  getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        model.close()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun openCamera()
    {
        cameraManager.openCamera(cameraManager.cameraIdList[0], object: CameraDevice.StateCallback(){
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            override fun onOpened(p0: CameraDevice) {
                cameraDevice = p0

                val surfaceTexture = textureView.surfaceTexture
                val surface  = Surface(surfaceTexture)
                val captureRequest = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW)
                captureRequest.addTarget(surface)

                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(listOf(surface), object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
                    override fun onConfigured(p0: CameraCaptureSession) {
                        p0.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequest.build(), null, null)
                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(p0: CameraCaptureSession) {
                    }
                }, handler)
            }

            override fun onDisconnected(p0: CameraDevice) {
            }

            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
            override fun onError(p0: CameraDevice, p1: Int) {
            }
        },handler)
    }

    private fun getPermission()
    {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 101)
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            getPermission()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using SSD-mobile net model
t-flite library support there output